# Image must be valid base64 format and file type must be .jpg format error

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64, retrofit

Ok this is first time that i am sending an image from gallery to server.I am useing SharedPrefernces to send image from fragment to viewmodel. My server expecting it as string.I am sending it as body with different data that my server excepting.But whe i try to send an image i am getting this error.

my fragment`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imgUriString = selectedImageUri.toString();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                binding.addReceiptIB.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SharedPref.setImagePath(bitMapToString(bitmap));
            
//            //send this encoded string to server
        //    imgUriString = selectedImageUri.toString();
//                binding.addReceiptIB.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            
        }
    }

public String bitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

`
and in my view model i am sending image like this:

```
 private Map<String, Object> body() {
    model.setMonth(month);
    model.setYear(year);

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("year", model.getYear());
    map.put("month", model.getMonth());
    map.put("memberId", model.getMemberId());
    map.put("expenseCategoryId", model.getExpenseCategoryId());
    map.put("expensePlace", model.getExpensePlace());
    map.put("date", model.getDate());
    map.put("amount", model.getAmount());
    map.put("note", model.getNote());
    map.put("image", model.getImage());
    Log.i("Sadrzaj mape", map.toString());
    return map;
}
```

this is how i receive that image also in my viewmodel:

```
public void onCickAddReceipt(View view) {
        model.setImage(SharedPref.getImagePath());
        callBack.onCickAddReceipt();
    }
```

what is weird i got some base64

```
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
```

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/736978/mobile/Image-valid-base-format-file

Comment: Yes i did, because i need an answer but few hours after i posted it here,and getting no answer

Comment: That's indeed base64 of a jpeg file; looks like a screenshot on a mobile screen. But if those 3988 characters are all you got, it's seriously cut off.

Comment: @Nyerguds you think that my sharedpref cut off base64?

Comment: I have no idea. All I can see is that what you put here in your question is cut down to just a fraction of the whole file.